# Move form from one div to another

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to move a form from one div to another onclick. Seems simple but it doesn't seem to work... Here's what I've got.

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
    $("#div2").append("#frm");
$("#div1").remove();
});



<div id="div1">
    <form id="frm"><input class="web" type="text"><span class="btn">go</form>
</div>

<div id="div2">
    content
</div>
```

Comment: I think your `<span>` is not closed just before the `</form>`. Is your HTML valid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$("#div2").append("#frm")` is appending the **string** `"#frm"` to `div2`, **not** the the form element itself whose `id` is `frm`. Append `$("#frm")` instead to add the form element:

```
$("#div2").append($("#frm"));
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XJBqU/)**.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to take the html content of div's 1 and move it to div's 2.

the form is the html content of div's 1, so in my example you can see that when the user clicks on the button i appending div's 1 contnet (the form) to div's 2

The code

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$(".btn").click(function() {
    $("#div2").append($("#div1").html());
$("#div1").remove();
});
```

});

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rjJbp/3/)

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method doesn't take a selector-string as one of its parameters, so right now you aren't targeting the form correctly; one option is to use [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) which *does* accept a selector-string, or you can simply wrap the string with a second jQuery object.

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
    $("#frm").appendTo("#div2");
    $("#div1").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
  $("#div2").append($('#frm').html());
  $("#div1").remove();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

[`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) does not accept a selector, so your selector is interpreted as content, create a jQuery object selecting `#frm` and pass it to `.append()`

```
$("#div2").append($("#frm"));
```

Also your span is missing its closing tag

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/A3DEX/)

Answer (score 0):

The jquery commands of the form in div 1 are not passed to the form of the div 2, why? The new form is not submitted as original.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".btn").click(function() {
     $("#div2").append($("#div1").html());
     $("#div1").remove();
   });
});
```

guys, I got this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".btn").click(function() {
    var master = $('#div1 > ').append();
    ('#div2').html(master);
     $("#div1").remove();
   });
});
```

Comment: My form: <form method="post" name="form-msg" id="form-msg" action="javascript:func()">